# HTTParty for Twitter, fails to authenticate when params included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, httparty

I'm trying to use the [verify_credentials endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) from the Twitter API. I want to set the `include_entities` param to `false`. I'm able to authenticate with the first example (so I know my `oauth_options` value is correct), but if I try to set the include_entities param, I get this error `{"code"=>32, "message"=>"Could not authenticate you."}`. Note: I cannot use the Twitter gem.

**WORKS:**

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", headers: {"Authorization" => oauth_options})
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", headers: {"Authorization" => oauth_options}, query: {include_entities: false})
```

**ALSO DOES NOT WORK**

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_entities=false", headers: {"Authorization" => oauth_options})
```

Comment: So including this query param will change the computed Authorization value since they are included in the signing process.  How are you generating that?

Comment: I did not realize that. I think that's what the problem is.

Comment: P.S., if you want to put this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you adjust the logic for computing the Authorization token, as it will need to consider query params.

Read the documentation here https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests or use a library that takes care of it automatically.

I can confirm it works if you sign the request correctly

```
$ oksocial 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_entities=false' | jq .
{
  "id": 111,
  "id_str": "111",
  "name": "Fred Blogs",
```

Comment: how can i do that?